# Strange Font in Linux Terminal

Tags: command-line

After I downloaded `php` and `blackeye` I get this weird font.
(ÛªÝ Äï÷îìïáäéîç Îçòïë®®®)
I tried to reinstall it but it wasn't the correct solution.

[image]

Comment: Try to select another font in Settings in the terminal.

Comment: I alredy tried this but it doesn't work. The font cames first when i press the Enter button. And then its still there. And doesn't go away eather i close restart the terminal

Comment: Try typing reset to reset the terminal. This works for me after I foolishly cat a binary file eg gzipped file by mistake.

Comment: No thats also not a solution. thats very strange :(